# Multimedia Player (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: sound, video, multimedia, video-player

I need a multimedia (specially video) player for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (somewhat like pot-player/km player )

Answer (score 0):

The 'Videos' app which comes as part of Ubuntu should work. You could also try [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)?

And there seem to be quite a few more that I haven't needed to try out.

Comment: Thanks @vandem

But actually I'm not satisfied with 'Videos' or 'VLC Media Player'.

I need something like pot-player/km player (that I use in windows)

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Then how about [Mplayer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPlayer) or [SMPlayer](http://lifehacker.com/5866656/the-best-video-player-for-linux)? They both seem to get good reviews...